# jQuery parent and child page

Tags: jquery

could anyone help me with that. I have a jquery lightbox. So I would like to use it as child page and as soon as you close it refresh update panel within parent page. I'm not sure how to set the relationship between page and lightbox. Thank u in advance for valuable examples :)

Answer (score 1):

Register an onclick event for the widget being used to close the lightbox.

Comment: I do need to refresh parent page from lightbox. and you didn't show  any example...